# Why is the message not showing up?

Tags: swift, popup

I created a pop up, but nothing is showing up, I added UIViewControllers as the pop ups. Why is it not working? http://puu.sh/hreL9/75081b2a90.png

```
class interestViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
        let interestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        interestViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        interestViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need a segue in this case. You can use the example I listed below. It shows a Popover from the button when you press it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

  var myPopover : UIPopoverPresentationController?

  @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // you can init your own View Controller here
    var popOverView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("interestViewController‌​") as! interestViewController
    popOverView.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 200);
    var destNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popOverView)
    destNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    self.myPopover = destNav.popoverPresentationController
    self.myPopover?.delegate = self
    self.myPopover?.sourceView = self.view
    var theFrame = sender.frame
    self.myPopover?.sourceRect = theFrame
    destNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    destNav.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.presentViewController(destNav, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }

  func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
  }

}
```

Comment: how would I add text or pictures to the pop up?

Comment: How would I init my own ViewController. I'm really new to swift

Comment: I added this 'let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(
            name: "Main",
            bundle: nil)
        var menuViewController: interestViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("interestViewController") as! interestViewController', but I get a SIBABRT error.

Comment: try this: var popOverView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("interestViewController") as! interestViewController

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ew6vuanyy8kn929/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2012.54.45.png?dl=0   https://www.dropbox.com/s/jewquz4d005ir2o/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2012.55.17.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgpjl3yso4552ao/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2012.56.18.png?dl=0 This is the button I click and get the error

Comment: show me upper lines of the error please, like: 2015-04-26 14:13:51.653 mySwift[3619:226782] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fa480c21420>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier '1my ViewController''

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdfrw0l4lwvaajp/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2013.17.23.png?dl=0

Comment: It says that you don't have a view with identifier "interestViewController‌". You need to add identifier to your interstViewController in the storyboard. https://www.dropbox.com/s/teqgv4xgk2v0sc6/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-26%20at%202.22.15%20PM.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I have a  view controller with all the stuff I want to put in the pop up. How do you get the text form that to view on the pop up w/o segue.

Comment: You didn't add a correct identifier to your view controller, thats why you are getting this error. If your View Controller works, it will work in popover as well. The code I posted above will present your View Controller as a popup.

Comment: I added this but it is still crashing https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5dqww81u67fa7m/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2013.48.02.png?dl=0

Comment: make sure you don't have a space after interestViewController‌, it may give you an error.

Comment: still getting an error. this is the current code https://www.dropbox.com/s/a32xdze3npdoo34/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2014.09.08.png?dl=0

Comment: The code if fine, the problem is in your storyboard. Xcode can't find a View Controller with "interestViewController" identifier.

Comment: This is what it looks like https://www.dropbox.com/s/l58nrhxscx2hncv/Screenshot%202015-04-26%2014.25.56.png?dl=0

Comment: The pop up works but I am not getting the words I printed on the other ViewController

Comment: If it works, please accept my answer. Maybe you don't see your info because you need to change a position of your labels, and put it closer to the top. Or you don't see it because you didn't set correct constraints. But those questions are out of this topic.